# Are paths in graph connected

Tags: algorithm, graph, path

I have a problem with paths in graph. We have a graph, for example:
5 verticles and 4 edges
1 2 first is connected to second, etc
2 3
3 4
5 1

And now I would like answer on questions(for example): 
If vertex 1 is conneted to 
vertex 3. Answer is YES - becauese we have path" 1 -> 2 -> 3.

What Do you advise me?

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at breadth-first/depth-first traversals.

Comment: Might be better to post this on programmers.stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

This will require some research on your part. The idea is to use a graph traversal algorithm like [depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Start from a vertex (like 1 in your example) and keep traversing the graph until you either reach the target node (3 in your example) or you cannot find any more paths to follow.

Answer (score 0):

DFS or BFS (I'd prefer DFS because it would result in less backtracking) from the starting node, if the algorithm completes without finding the node it is not reachable.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I must answer on every request. Count of vericles is 1000, and Edges 250 000.

Comment: Is the graph changing with each request? If yes, that's unfortunate, you'll need to traverse it. Otherwise you can cache the result, so on the first request you know 1->3 is true, cache that and on the next request for 1->3 you can just get it out of the cache.